# GCP Cloud Terminal will not write file to my Windows filesystem

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terminal, cloud

I'm trying to extract the schema from some tables in our BigQuery instance.  I can get the output to push to the terminal/console, but I can't get it to write to my local filesystem.  Here are a couple permutations I've tried, to no avail.

```
xander@cloudshell:~ (our-gcp_project-prod)$ bq show --format=prettyjson --schema=true our-gcp_project-prod:my_dataset.v_encounters > C:\_data\scripts\my_dataset-v_encounters_testing.txt
xander@cloudshell:~ (our-gcp_project-prod)$ bq show --format=prettyjson --schema=true our-gcp_project-prod:my_dataset.v_encounters > my_dataset_v_encounters_testing.txt
xander@cloudshell:~ (our-gcp_project-prod)$ bq show --format=prettyjson --schema=true our-gcp_project-prod:my_dataset.v_encounters > localhost:my_dataset_v_encounters_testing.txt
xander@cloudshell:~ (our-gcp_project-prod)$ bq show --format=prettyjson --schema=true our-gcp_project-prod:my_dataset.v_encounters > localhost:~my_dataset_v_encounters_testing.txt
```

I've tried dozens of different syntax, but nothing seems to write the file to anywhere on my laptop.  Need help understanding how to change the syntax to output the file locally on my laptop (Windows PC).

Comment: You show the commands but not the error messages. Note: only the first two commands are valid on Windows. The last two specify invalid destinations.

Comment: The cloudshell is running in your local machine?

Comment: @John Hanley - Thanks for your response.  You are spot on.  There is no error message.  All the statements run without throwing an error, even the last two that shouldn't work on a PC.

Comment: I can run the bq show command and get the output to terminal, but it won't save to the local machine.

Comment: @Puteri - Yes the Cloud Shell is running in my local machine.

Comment: @MarcAlexander cloud shell never run on  your local machine it runs on the cloud (thus its name!). You can see it on your browser on your local machine but it's a remote shell of a VM running in the cloud. Use a windows terminal (powershell, WSL2) with gcloud installed on it and the correct authentication, to access Google Cloud resources and your local resources (your disk)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere you are right.  I needed to be using the Google SDK installed on my machine to access the local resources.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like `guillaume blaquiere` described, the shell which you are using now is the Cloudshell and it is a CLI provided by Google to perform command based operations in GCP and all the data you store in that CLI will be stored on cloud.

If you want to download that data to your local machine you can click on the cloud editor option and go to the path where you have stored those files and double click on the file, you can find an option to download the file and for more information on how to access and use cloud editor you can go through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/introducing-cloud-shell-editor).

If you don’t want to proceed in the way stated above, you can follow what **guillaume** suggested, [download the gcloud sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#windows) and  perform the [required authentication process](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing). Now run your commands to save the data to your local machine.

Comment: Yes - I needed to be running a Local instances of the Cloud Shell to access the local resources.  Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge.